# How to share a variable AND it's value in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, global-variables

I have surfed quite a lot about this. But the results that I've got tells me that either I should use appDelegate or singleton etc.
All of which produces the same result. i.e I am able to share a variable in different ViewControllers but as soon as the ViewController gets changed , the variable looses it's value. 
For example I used a variable named myVar of type int. I declared it in AppDelegate and then I'm able to use it in all the ViewControllers with the help of AppDelegate. But as soon as I move from A ViewController to B ViewController the value of the myVar variable gets "0" again. I don't want that . I want the variable to hold it's value. And I don't want to pass this data with the help of pushViewController etc. Please suggest me a good solution.

```
AppDelegate.h

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, assign) int myVar;

@end

FirstViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
AppDelegate* app = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

app.myVar = 1;
NSLog(@"%d",app.myVar);  //Shows "1" in Log  
}


SecondViewController.m

- (IBAction)pressButton:(id)sender{
AppDelegate * app = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

  NSLog(@"%d",app.myVar);  // Shows "0" in Log (But I want it to show "1" as I have already set "myVar" value as "1" in my FirstViewController)


}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Perhaps you could show some code demonstrates the problem?

Comment: post some code, you must be doing some thing wrong, otherwise app delegate works fine.

Comment: You're lying.  That code won't fail the way you describe.  What is the REAL code?

Comment: (Although I'm a little unsure what a `strong` attribute is supposed to do to an `int`.)

Comment: Give me ONE reason why would I lie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@property (strong, assign) int myVar;` is declaring both `strong` and `assign`. As an int, it should only be `assign`, not `strong`. `strong` would be used for Objective-c objects, `assign` for primitive C properties.

I think what you want is the following:

`@property (assign, nonatomic) int myVar;`

Comment: It may not have solved your problem, but it's still going to help you avoid other problems.

Comment: From the code you posted here, there are no other indicators of a problem, so you would benefit from posting more code to help solve your problem. If there is any other code which affects `myVar`, you'll want to examine it and post it here for us to take a look, otherwise we may not be able to provide much help.

Comment: Thanx for your time. You are right. I checked the same code in separate project. And It WORKED. But it's not working in the porject where I want :P. Must be my bad .

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your code there are some error

```
AppDelegate.h

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (nonatomic, assign) int myVar;
```

And check it gives same value in FirstViewController.m and SecondViewController.m

Comment: You can download code from https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s3yqezs99cfntt6/AABujBuP853KJEZRqzKajTkCa?dl=0  and check it.
It was working.

Answer (score -1):

if your var is a NSString, you can simple use the [copy] protocol. e.g.

NSString *eString = [cString copy];

If it is an object, you need to implement the [copy] protocol for that class.